# delete from database when certain string occurs n times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with table `a` with column `b`.

```
      b
1   a-b
2     a
3 a-b-c
```

how can I delete all rows from the table where `-` occurs more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like:

```
delete from t
    where b like '%-%-%';
```

Comment: perhaps _ to -  ?